# mollview command not returning plot image

Tags: plot, healpy

I'm new to healpy and I'm trying to plot the following in iPython27:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp

NSIDE = 32
m=np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))
hp.mollview(m, title="Mollview image RING")
```

This does not return an image as I was expecting. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup IPython to display matplotlib plots.

If you are using IPython console

```
%matplotlib
```

If IPython notebook

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know about the iPython notebook.
I usually use gedit when coding - is there any way of making this work with a .py file? Or is that counter productive?

Comment: Usual way is to open IPython, configure matplotlib and then `%run` your .py script.